# Regex to extract values between 2 underscores, including a value that is an underscore

Tags: regex, r

I am working in R and and trying to extract part of a character string separated with underscores, including an underscore:

```
WRAP_384_p1_QC1_8
WRAP_384_p3_QC1_7
```

I wish to obtain an output like this:

```
1_QC1
3_QC1
```

What regex do I need to extract this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match one or more characters (`.*`) followed by a `_` followed by a lower case letter (`[a-z]`) or `|` a `_` followed by one or more numbers (`\\d+`) until the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blanks (`""`).

```
gsub(".*_[a-z]|_\\d+$", "", str1)
#[1] "1_QC1" "3_QC1"
```

---

Or use `sub` with capture groups to match two instances of one or more not a underscore followed by a underscore (`([^_]+_){2}`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a lower case letter (`[a-z]`), and then we capture the group within the brackets (`(...)`) for one  or more numbers (`\\d+`) followed by `_` and one or more alpha numeric characters (`[[:alnum:]]+`) close the capture group bracket followed by underscore (`_`) and one or more numbers (`\\d+`).  We replace it with the second capture group (`\\2`).

```
sub("^([^_]+_){2}[a-z](\\d+_[[:alnum:]]+)_\\d+", "\\2", str1)
#[1] "1_QC1" "3_QC1"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("WRAP_384_p1_QC1_8", "WRAP_384_p3_QC1_7")
```